Feepayer issue while swap
I am facing the issue while swapping the tokens using Jupiter API, I want to swap from other and feepayer will be another account.
while swapping the feepayer account error show:
Error Swap: Cannot sign with non signer key HAD84928941Nt*****
const userWalletAddress = userWallet.payer.publicKey.toString();
const payerWalletAddress = payerWallet.payer.publicKey.toString();

const swapTransaction = await (
      await fetch("https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          quoteResponse,
          userPublicKey: userWalletAddress,
          wrapUnwrapSOL: wrapUnwrapSOL,
          dynamicComputeUnitLimit: true,
          prioritizationFeeLamports: "auto",
        }),
      })
    ).json();
    const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(
      swapTransaction.swapTransaction,
      "base64"
    );
    var transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);
    const getblockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized");
    transaction.recentBlockhash = getblockhash.blockhash;
    transaction.feePayer = payerWallet.payer.publicKey;
    transaction.sign([userWallet.payer , payerWallet.payer]);
    const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();
    const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
      skipPreflight: true,
      maxRetries: 20,
      preflightCommitment: "processed",
    });
    await connection.confirmTransaction(txid, "finalized");
    console.log(`https://solscan.io/tx/${txid}`);


Please edit your code to show how you're getting userWalletAddress

userWalletAddress is basically userWallet.payer.publickey.

@Ahri - Check Now
