Using jupiter swap instructions for faster transactions
Just looking at jupiter's documentation.
I notice it has /swap and /swap-instructions
It appears that /swap-instructions gives you an instruction payload with which to utilise transactions in a solana VersionedTransaction, as opposed to using /swap to pass through your quote.
Is there any benefit to doing this? Would it result in a faster creation of VersionedTransaction or is the difference negligible to the point that the use case is for something else?

Performance-wise, it doesn't change anything (after all /swap is just a Transaction/VersionTransaction populated with the contents of /swap-instructions). The reason this endpoint exists is for composability with other programs, i.e. you want to add other instructions before and/or after your swap in the same transaction.

Hi, I want to use feepayer account to another wallet. Is this possible in Jupiter as Jupiter signed the versioned transaction?

I suggest opening another question for this as this isn't directly related to this question.

https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/15165/feepayer-issue-while-swap?noredirect=1#comment10590_15165
